# Easiest way to run .NET 4.5 code in Unity 5 For UWP

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

Differing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079409/using-net-4-5-code-in-unity-5), I realise that Unity uses a modified version of .Net 3.5. Thus I revised available options to one of the following:

1- create a TCP server/client to communicate between library and Unity project

2- Use database as messaging system

My question, is there a simpler way I am missing to get my dll to work on Unity?
Note that I just want my Unity project to build for the Universal Windows Platform

Comment: Easy: Unity doesn't accept .NET 4.5. UWP (for Windows 10) needs .NET 4.5. Result: you can't do this.

Comment: I realise that I cannot do this right away, that's why I provided that two methods below, my question was if there was a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using signalR as a local communication server between my .NET4.5 code and Unity .NET code.

More information in this [blog post](https://ultimatecode.wordpress.com/2016/02/21/signalr-for-unity3d-to-universal-app-communication-part-1/)