# Manually adding .NET 4.5 scripts to Unity: Potential issues?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I've recently had to some work in Unity that required classes only available in the later versions of .NET, which Unity does not yet support. I managed to download the very few scripts that I was missing and added it to my project and it seems to work fine. What I wanted to know is why can I not just take the entire .NET source and shove it into my projects? What are the implications of doing something like that?

EDIT: The scripts that I have added so far was the generic version of WeakReference as well as any dependencies that it needed (Contract in System.Diagnostics.Contract).

EDIT EDIT: I basically want to know why I can't simply just the C# class files found in the later versions of .NET to Unity, which uses an older version of .NET. Is it a software issue? Is it a hardware issue? Is it because Unity's system components were built in correspondence with the earlier version of .NET?

Comment: What .NET 4.5 features in particular are you leveraging in your scripts? You haven't provided us many details in that regard, so identifying potential problems isn't possible without being overly broad.

Comment: Unity uses a very old Mono build, so it does not support .NET 4.5 profile very well. You can only safely use .NET 4 compatible things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

Install the [Visual Studio Tools for Unity](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SebastienLebreton.VisualStudio2015ToolsforUnity) (it should automatically get installed when you install Unity), when you do you can tell your .csproj in the "target framework" drop-down to target the special version of .NET Unity uses and you will only be able to compile dll's that have methods and types that Unity supports.

---

**LONG ANSWER:**

It is because Unity does not use the installed version of .NET on your computer. Unity uses [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), and a very old version at that. This allows unity to be ran on multiple platforms and OSes. Because of that you can only use features that are in the supported version of Mono.

However, if you look [at their roadmap](https://unity3d.com/unity/roadmap) the alpha build you will see

> **Scripting: C# Compiler Upgrade**
>   Upgrade Mono C# compiler against our
>   current .Net 2.0 and 2.0 Subset profiles. Note that this is an upgrade
>   of the C# compiler only, not the full Mono runtime

Then further on in the "research" phase

> **Scripting: .NET Profile Upgrade**
>   Upgrade .Net profile to 4.6 enabling access to the latest .Net functionality and APIs.

---

**UPDATE:**

You can get a experimental build that uses the 4.6 profile from [the stickied post here](https://forum.unity3d.com/forums/experimental-scripting-previews.107/).

Here are the notes for the [5.6.0b5 beta release](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/upgraded-mono-net-in-editor-and-some-players-on-5-6-0b5.454387/)

> - For this release, the Editor and the following players should be working:
>
>   - Windows, OSX, Linux standalone
>   - iOS with IL2CPP
>   - Android with IL2CPP and Mono
> - Other platforms are known to not work yet, and are probably not worth installing.
> - Managed debugging via Visual Studio Tools for Unity or MonoDevelop is *not supported* in this release. If you want to use VSTU for
>     editing please use the special build linked at the bottom of this
>     post.
> - The compiler targets the C# 6 language.
> - The compiler **by default** will still target the .Net 4.6 framework profile.
> - Known issues
>
>   - The Android/Mono build does not work properly with managed code stripping. Please disable managed code stripping for now.
>   - For some projects, the Windows standalone player can crash on Windows 8.1. This is intermittent, so we would love to see any crash
>       reports or data about this

Comment: To the person who downvoted, please let me know why you thought my answer was not useful so I can correct it.

Comment: So as Mono is a .NET framework and is designed for cross-platform applications, it only contains a subset of the full set of classes in .NET? Hence, as Unity is built on top of Mono, you can only uses classes supported by Mono?

Comment: Correct, you can only use classes supported by the version of mono Unity uses. Modern Mono can do a lot of .NET 4.5 but Unity is not yet using modern Mono, but it is on their roadmap to update.

Comment: Thank you, that is all I wanted to know.

Comment: The current status as of June 2017:
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/future-plans-for-the-mono-runtime-upgrade.464327/

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079409/using-net-4-5-code-in-unity-5). Like I described in your other question, you can "inject" newer stuff and use them, but sooner or later they'll backfire (e.g. can't compile to particular systems, can compile but cannot be published in whatever mobile store, surprisingly slow execution, huge builds, etc. Worst case your project will be compromised).
If you really cannot refactor the project you are working on and you feel you must use 'up-to-date technology', bear in mind the injected classes code must be data objects, means, not at all related to [GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html)s.
It is also adviced to derive from [ScriptableObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) when and where possible.
**EDIT**: But I'd recommend what I told you earlier (refactor) or what the linked answer describes ('export' the code incompatible with mono/.net2.0 to an external dll and use it from there)